# How does one remove extra dates in mathplotlib x axis?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a bit of an issue. It's annoying actually. Basically I am plotting some earnings and revenue data onto the chart. I have zero problems doing so. The issue arises with the dates on the chart. On the x-axis the dates go from 2016.0, 2016.5 etc etc. 
See here:
[image]

Can someone help me make the dates be a whole number?

see my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
import matplotlib

quarterly=[{'date': '2Q2019', 'revenue': 53809000000, 'earnings': 10044000000},
{'date': '3Q2019', 'revenue': 64040000000, 'earnings': 13686000000},
{'date': '4Q2019', 'revenue': 91819000000, 'earnings': 22236000000},
{'date': '1Q2020', 'revenue': 58313000000, 'earnings': 11249000000}]

annual = [{'date': 2016, 'revenue': 215639000000, 'earnings': 45687000000}, {'date': 2017, 'revenue': 229234000000, 'earnings': 48351000000},
{'date': 2018, 'revenue': 265595000000, 'earnings': 59531000000}, {'date': 2019, 'revenue': 260174000000, 'earnings': 55256000000}]


dates,revs,earns=[],[],[]
for a in annual:
    dates.append(a['date'])
    revs.append(a['revenue'])
    earns.append(a['earnings'])



fig, ax = p.subplots()
ax.set_title('Earnings')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_ylabel('Amount in $')

ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

p.plot(dates,revs,'-o',label='revenues')
p.plot(dates,earns,'-o',label='earnings')
p.legend()
p.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `pandas`, this type of analysis is what it's for

- convert date from `int64` to `str`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe from your list of dicts
annual = pd.DataFrame(annual)

# convert date from int64 to str
annual.date = annual.date.astype('str')

# plot
plt.plot(annual.date, annual.revenue, label='revenue')
plt.plot(annual.date, annual.earnings, label='earnings')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]